# $p$-th roots of unity adjoined to a $\mathfrak{p}$-adic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity, local-field

I want to prove the following:

> Let $k$ be a number field and $S$ a set of primes of $k$ containing the primes $S_p$ that lie over the rational prime $p$. Then the extension of $k$ by the group of $p$-th roots of unity, $k(\mu_p) | k$, is unramified outside $S$.

The first step is, that for $\mathfrak{p} \notin S$ we have $\nu_\mathfrak{p}(p) =0$. Therefore the extension of the localisations at $\mathfrak{p}$, $k_\mathfrak{p}(\mu_p) | k_\mathfrak{p}$, is unramified. Why?
The next step is already the conclusion but I don't see it either.

It must be pretty easy, maybe someone can give me a hint? 
Is there an alternative way of proving the above statement?

Thank you, Tom

Comment: factor the minimal polynomial mod $p$

Comment: i meant mod $\ell$ for $\ell \neq p$.

Comment: @hunter Thanks for your quick response. Could you elaborate a bit more on that? I interpret your comment as if I have to factor the minimal polynomial of a primitive $p$-th root of unity, $\zeta_p$ modulo $l$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an elaboration on my comment. The minimal polynomial for $\zeta$ divides $x^p - 1$. This polynomial has distinct roots in any finite field of characteristic $\ell \neq p$ (proof: it is obviously coprime to its derivative since the only root of the derivative is $0$ for $\ell \neq p$), so at any prime away from $p$ your field extension is unramified.

You may find this document helpful to understand the general principle being used here, which is the key tool for computing the splitting behavior of primes in extensions of number fields:

http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/dedekindf.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. This may be kind of elementary, but what is the relation to the fact that $\nu_\mathfrak{p}(p) = 0$? And how are those primes $\mathfrak{p}$ related to your argumentation? Third question: How does it follow that distinct roots imply that the extension is unramified? Thank you :-)